# the datasource sets to mat table(angular) has data but doesnt display any data and the table is empty

Tags: angular, mat-table

The mat table (angular) datasource has a data(array with one row) but just displays the header and the table is empty.

The problem is that the console in ngOnInit shows data, but my table is empty and only displays a header. What's wrong with my simple code?

Code in my component html file:

```html
<div class="mat-elevation-z8 show-feature">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="samples">
    <!-- from Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef = "let row">
        {{row.name}}
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef='displayedColumns'>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-header-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

Code in my component ts file:

```ts
export class SpliceConnectionsAttributeControl implements 
        AfterContentInit, OnInit, OnDestroy {


  samples: Samples[];
  displayedColumns = ['name'];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.samples = [{name: 'test1'}];
    console.log(this.samples);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() { }
}
```

Model:

```ts
export class Samples {
  name: string ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template syntax is wrong, you should use `table`, `th`, `tr` and `td` tags with angular material directives:

```html
<table mat-table #table [dataSource]="samples">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
       {{row.name}}
     </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef='displayedColumns'></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

**DEMO: [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgyjtl?file=app/table-basic-example.ts)**

Comment: I really appreciate your time and your help by even providing a demo which absolutely resolve the problem.

Comment: You are very welcome. So did it solve your issue? If so, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer, which marks the question as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `mat-row` element is inside your `mat-header-row` element. See https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3jszti